# How to detect cpu/gpu performance on web app

Tags: javascript, performance, css-animations

Maybe it is possible by indirectly looking for it, maybe something like looking for `window.WebAssembly && window.Worker` maybe but I'm not really sure what works. It should be a very generic and stable solution.

In addition to [Using javascript to detect device CPU/GPU performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002195/using-javascript-to-detect-device-cpu-gpu-performance), it should be a very simple test without having to do any WebGL or similar tests.

---

The css animation I use has the following keyframes:

```
 animation: bgRotation 240s linear infinite;

 @keyframes bgRotation {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: -4000px 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I know you're asking about detecting CPU/GPU performance - but I suppose ideally you would prefer that the animation was just smooth in all cases? How are you animating the rotation? This seems related/duplicate, using `navigator.hardwareConcurrency`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516931/how-to-get-cpu-usage-in-javascript

Comment: @Jeppe I have a css animation where the background position changes of a fullscreen hd image. Well, `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` seems to be a good starting point. But what if there are multiple cpu but slower ones? And what about gpu? Isn't this even more important for such animations? On a Redmi 12 for example, it is slow, even though there are 8 cpu in total: https://www.mi.com/global/product/redmi-12/specs/

Comment: Can you show the CSS animation code? There are different ways to do it that might be more/less cpu intensive.

Comment: You can also explore the Performance API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API)

Comment: @Jeppe I added the css code to the description

Comment: Yes, you can get better performance with `transform` then. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906196/improve-css3-background-position-animations-performance

Comment: OK, but then the browser should optimize the rendering of a changing background position if this hack needs to be made. However, I can't use transform since the background has elements that are rendered inline and should stay where the are...

Comment: Okay - I think you need to update your question, so it is either specifically about detecting CPU performance, or animating a background without animating its content (or ask that in a new question). And then add the html etc.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the input. I focussed it on the CPU performance part now.